# Figure in Latex is not centering despite using \centering

Tags: latex

I am very new to LaTex and am trying to center a figure.

I have tried to use the package `float` using both `[h]` and `[H]`, I have tried to add `\centering` and I have tried to wrap the image in `\begin{center} \end{centering}` but nothing seems to work.

My full code is as such

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\title{Dissertation}
\author{GC}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{my_grades}
    \caption{grades plot}
    \label{fig:grade}
\end{figure}

This figure does not seem to want to centre

\end{document}
```

This figure on the compiled document looks as such. If someone could help me understand why this doesn't want to move that would be great:

[image]

Comment: Try with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{my_grades}`.  Your image is probably too large to fit in the available space.

Comment: This has centered it although made it much smaller. Why would this be too large as looking above, clearly there is room for the leftmost border to be in line with the Introduction title?

Comment: I don't have your figure, but my best guess would be that some white space is part of the figure. (I don't know if this is your real figure or just a dummy image, but I would definitely scale it down so that the fontsize of he axis labels matches the one from the surrounding document)

Comment: Try `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` to test horizontal page margins!! :)

Comment: If you want to keep your figure wider than the textwidth, there is a solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems fine, I just added a [width=50mm] in your include graphics and it centered the Figure.

I would check two issues:

1. Is your figure to larger than the textwidth?
2. Does your Figure has a white part on its lefthand side?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }

\title{Dissertation}
\author{GC}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=50mm]{darth-vader_5yvm.jpeg}
    \caption{grades plot}
    \label{fig:grade}
\end{figure}

This figure does not seem to want to centre

\end{document}
```

[image: Latex Output]